# Disable or Read-Only - a select box issue

Tags: php, html, yii

On this form, I have some input field and select boxes that should not be edited by some users.

However, I need those unable fields to be inserted anyway.

I'm thinking about passing those values to a hidden field (should this be done in js ?);
And submit the form by using those hidden fields instead.

Is this a good approach ? Please advice.

Comment: Hidden fields have been around since the dawn of forms. Yes, use them.

Comment: Well, technically someone could use a DOM inspector or Javascript console and read/change the value. But that's not a _new_ concern, pretty much any method you choose will have this weakness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them in [hidden field](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#hiddenField-detail):

```
echo $form->hiddenField($model,'property');
```

Comment: Thanks for the Yii specific reply. Quick Yii related question: Some of those forms are required, on the client side as well. If I `disable` those fields, will Yii ignore that validation on those fields ?

Comment: You handle different operation on the same model/form with different scenarios. You need to look into scenarios http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/

Comment: You have a point there. I will re-think the all thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hidden fields to pass the data in to your form, but bear in mind that if someone's planning mischief, they can edit the values with tools like Firebug and submit them anyway, so relying on hidden fields may lead to issues.

If you want to be properly secure, you'll have to do everything on the server side - check to see if the client has permission to access those fields when they submit the form. If they do, take the values they've submitted; otherwise, use default values stored in your PHP code instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just use hidden feilds within your form, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="00001" />
```

No js is required.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with disabled on checkboxes and maybe readonly on text fields. The thing is that you KNOW what value they should have when they are submited. So on server side you can just ignore them and use the value you have choosen. And ignore the data if someone is manipulating the post request.